# How to make apache service run continuously from script file from docker?

Tags: command-line, bash, apache-http-server, script, docker

I am trying to run apache2 service from `.sh` script from dockerfile. The 'sh' script contains 3 executable commands which is presented as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
 export DISPLAY=:0.0
 echo "pvw launcher file execution started"

 /home/data/pv/pv-5.9.0/bin/pvpython /home/data/pvw/conf/launcher.json &

 echo "pvw launcher file execution done"

 echo "Apache2 frontend exectution"
 exec apachectl -D FOREGROUND 

 echo "Starting gunicorn"
 exec python -m gunicorn --bind 172.17.0.2:9002 --keep-alive 100 --log-file temp.txt --log-level debug --timeout 600 wsgi:app
```

Based on this, the CMD in the dockerfile is presented as `CMD ./start.sh`.

Now, when I run the the docker image, the container runs till apache2 and holds the terminal there.

I want the container to execute apache2 service, run continuously and move to next command (gunicorn) in the 'sh' script and execute the gunicorn command. How should I modify the 'sh' script for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing Apache HTTPd in the foreground, so it's doing exactly what you're asking it to do. What you want to do is *daemonize* Apache, so script execution can continue.

How do to this depends on the way you (or your distribution) has set up Apache, but generally the following will do:

`apachectl start`

instead of `apachectl -D FOREGROUND`.

Do take note that by daemonizing the process, you're losing the parent-child relationship with the docker process, so things like `docker stop` might stop working or wait until their timeout before killing Apache. Also, if Apache dies, Docker won't notice and won't automatically restart the container.

A better solution would be to have Apache and Gunicorn in separate Docker containers. If you can't do this for some reason, use some process manager like `supervisord` to manage the processes within the container.

Comment: Hi @mtak,  

I tried by using `apachectl start` and also with `service apache2 start`, these command runs till apache and stops the container process and does not move towards gunicorn command. Any other work around needed?

Will definitely try with supervisord if this complicates things.

Comment: You did remove the "exec" ?

Comment: Indeed, what @GerardH.Pille says. `exec` replaces the shell script with the Apache daemon, thus exiting your script. I assumed you knew about `exec` since you use it in your existing script, but you know what they say about assumptions ;)

Comment: @mtak and GerardH.Pille, thanks for the basic understanding of exec command which I had missed in the bash script. Now, it is working.